# iOS10. Swift. UIPageViewController memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, memory-leaks

I have implemented CustomPageViewController which is subclass of UIPageViewController.
It has array of created ViewControllers

While running my app, I noticed that on every swipe(transition from one page to another) memory used by application increases, and memory usage is a non decreasing function of number of performed transitions from one page to the other.

While debugging, in order to solve this issue, I added deinit method and print statement to ViewDidLoad & deinit - ViewDidLoad is called once, and deist isn't called at all while swiping.

In order to make sure that this behavior isn't because of a source leakage in my CustomViewControllers I added ViewControllers with some buttons instead my custom classes, but memory leaks remained.

I have noticed a lot of questions on SO, with the same issue, for iOS versions since 8, most of them relates to objC, and in the rest no solution is given.

Do you use UIPageViewController? If so have you ever noticed that it leaks memory? As functionality it provides: to swipe among set of views is of high demand, how you implement that? Did you implement your own version, or fixed existing?

Comment: What type of webview are you using? Are you certain that the real culprit isn't the webview? uiWebView, wkWebView, and even Safari are all notorious for inherent memory leaks.

Comment: @Vemonus I am not using webview at al